# Pandas pd.str.contains not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe structure that looks like the following

```
name         | injury
Kevin Durant   Torn Achilles (out for season)
```

I am attempting to query the dataframe to get specific rows that match a name and injury like the following

```
df[df['name'].str.fullmatch('Kevin Durant') & df['injury'].str.fullmatch('Torn Achilles (out for season)']
```

However, this gives me an empty dataframe instead of the expected result (the row I showed at the start)

What's interesting is that if I drop the `(out for season)` portion and change `fullmatch` to `contains` I get the desired result as such:

```
df[df['name'].str.fullmatch('Kevin Durant') & df['injury'].str.contains('Torn Achilles')]
```

Which leads me to believe something in relation to the parenthesis in `(out for season)` is causing the `fullmatch` to not work correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: "fullmatch" expects a regular expression and parentheses have a special meaning in them. Replace `'Torn Achilles (out for season)'` by `r'Torn Achilles \(out for season\)'`. The parentheses are then interpreted as they are.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you! Was not aware of this.